# How do I set the securityContext in kubernetes deployment?

Tags: docker

I would like to set sysctl in deployment.

It works in yaml below.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: sysctl-example
spec:
  securityContext:
    sysctls:
    - name: kernel.sem
      value: "1000 1000 32000 1000"
  containers:
    - name: dummy-pod
      image: ubuntu
  restartPolicy: Never
```

but, I don't know how to configure it in deployment.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      securityContext:
        sysctls:
        - name: kernel.sem
          value: "1000 32000 1000 1000"
     containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

It prints an error.

error: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 20: did not find expected key

Answer (score 0):

In deployment apiVersion extensions/v1beta1, deployment.spec.template.spec.containers has securityContext in its field instead of a Pod, where it's deployment.spec.

```
$ kubectl explain deployment.spec.template.spec.containers
KIND:     Deployment
VERSION:  extensions/v1beta1

RESOURCE: containers <[]Object>
...
   securityContext  <Object>
     Security options the pod should run with. More info:
     https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/security-context/ More info:
     https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/
...
```